# Unable to change the title of UITableViewRowAction from Favorite to Remove when the data exists in the array swift

Tags: ios, swift

On swipe left the tableview cell a button with title Favorite appear which save the current row title in defaults on second time swiping left the same button the Favorite button removes the current cell title from array in defaults. On second time when I swipe left I want the title as Remove not favorite. Please Help.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        var titleFavoriteButton = "Favorite"
        let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: 
         "Favorite") { [unowned self] (action, indexPath) in

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var favorites = defaults.array(forKey: "favorites") as? [String] ?? []

            if let datastring = itemList[indexPath.row] as? String {
                if favorites.contains(datastring) {
                    favorite.title = "Remove"
                     favorites.remove(at: favorites.index(of: datastring)!)
            } else {
                    favorites.append(datastring)
            }
            defaults.set(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
            }
            print(favorites)
                }
             return [favorite]
 }
```

Here is the working output
[image: Here is the working output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the favorite exists **before** creating the action

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var favorites = defaults.array(forKey: "favorites") as? [String] ?? []
    let item = itemList[indexPath.row]

    let favoriteIndex = favorites.firstIndex(of: item)
    let actionTitle = favoriteIndex == nil ? "Favorite" : "Remove"
    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: actionTitle) { (action, indexPath) in
        if let index = favoriteIndex {
            favorites.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            favorites.append(item)
        }

        defaults.set(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
        print(favorites)
    }
    return [favorite]
}
```

Comment: Love u sir, Worked like a charm.